# Assignment operator cannot be used in if statements?

Tags: if-statement, comparison-operators, game-maker

It appears that in Game Maker 8, 8.1, and Studio (at least) that the assignment operator `=` is identical to the comparison operator `==`. For example, these lines do the same thing:

```
if (a=b) {}
if (a==b) {}
```

Is this function meant to be friendly to new users? Should I continue using `==` or switch to `=`? Or does it make no difference?

P.S. Things like incrementing still work with `=` similarly to `==`:

```
if a=b++{} //b is still incremented, but a does not change
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality was left over from previous versions as stated in the GameMaker help file.

> "However, this is a legacy from old GameMaker versions and you should use the == operators for comparing and = for assigning."

It would be good practice for you to use `==` when comparing as that is what it is designed for.  Also, if you were to move onto another languages like PHP, using the `=` operator would actually initialize the variable in the if statement.  This could give you quite a headache if you are in the habit of using the single `=` operator.

Comment: Yet other languages such as pascal/delphi treat "=" as comparison sign and ":=" as assignment operation. - This is hence reflected in gamemaker (one can use := as well as = for assignment).